# When column values are equal then value, otherwise NULL while GROUPING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, distinct

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Col_1 VARCHAR(50),
    Col_2 VARCHAR(50),
    Col_3 VARCHAR(50)
);
```

and sample data:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    Col_1,
    Col_2,
    Col_3
)
VALUES
  ('1', '2', '3')
, ('1', '2', '3')
, ('1', '21', '4')
, ('1', '21', '5')
, ('1', '31', '8')
, ('1', '31', '8')
, ('1', '31', '8')
, ('3', '41', '1')
, ('3', '41', '2')
```

What I want is to get `col_3` when all values are equal, otherwise it should be `NULL`, when I group by `col_1`, `col_2`. So the desired result looks like this:

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
1         2      3
1         21     NULL
1         31     8
3         41     NULL
```

What I've managed to do is just to count unique values, however I cannot get the value of `col_3`

```
SELECT 
  t.Col_1
, t.Col_2
, COUNT(DISTINCT t.Col_3) AS DistinctCount
FROM @tbl AS t
GROUP BY t.Col_1,
         t.Col_2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `case` expression. I would recommend:

```
select col_1, col_2, 
    case when min(col_3) = max(col_3) then min(col_3) end col_3
from @tbl
group by col_1, col_2
```

You *could* also use `count(distinct)`, as in your initial attempt:

```
select col_1, col_2, 
    case when count(distinct col_3) = 1 then min(col_3) end col_3
from @tbl
group by col_1, col_2
```

However, I suspect that the first query is more efficient. `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is quite expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t.Col_1, t.Col_2,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(t.col_3) = MAX(t.col3) THEN MIN(t.col_3) END) as col_3
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.Col_1, t.Col_2
```